# Waterline migrate existing database to waterline models without sails

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

```
 Error (E_UNKNOWN) :: Encountered an unexpected error
: Trying to define a collection (external_resource) which already exists.
```

I am trying to create a model for an existing database. I am NOT using sails. Just waterline stand-alone.I have the connection set to migrate safe. However, waterline is still trying to create a table that already exists in my pre-existing database. If I make the tableName a new name, it works fine. The problem seems to be when I try to use existing data in an existing table and then create a waterline model for it.

I believe this is a bug since migrate safe should never be trying to create a table at all right?

I am using waterline without sails.

Waterline is configured like this:

````
```
models = [];
fs.readdirSync(HOMEDIR + '/lib/models/waterline').forEach(function(file) {
  models.push(require(HOMEDIR + '/lib/models/waterline/' + file));
});

module.exports = {
  init: function(next) {
    models.forEach(function(model) {
      orm.loadCollection(model);
    });

    orm.initialize(config, function(err, models) {
      if (err) throw err;
      global.models = models.collections;
      global.connections = models.connections;
      next();
    });
  }
};


//And this in my config
localhost: {
      migrate: 'safe',
      adapter: 'postgres',
      database: 'intellinote',
      host: 'localhost',
      user: 'postgres',
      password: '',
      port: 5432
    }
```
````

using sails-postgresql by the way. "sails-postgresql": "^0.11.4",

One hypothesis I have is that my model definition does not match my postgresql model exactly. I have tried to do this but maybe I missed something small. Where in the waterline code does it check for model == schema definition? Maybe if I knew that, I could find why this is trying to do a create

Sails user for 3 years. Major production level bug at multi billion company :(

Thanks in advance

More info: The sql looks like this for the table

````
```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "intellinotedb"."external_resource";
CREATE TABLE "intellinotedb"."external_resource" (
    "id" int8 NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('external_resource_id_seq'::regclass),
    "external_id" varchar(2000) NOT NULL COLLATE "default",
    "version_id" varchar(2000) COLLATE "default",
    "url" varchar(5000) COLLATE "default",
    "name" varchar(4000) COLLATE "default",
    "size" int8,
    "creator" varchar(50) NOT NULL COLLATE "default",
    "created_at" timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
    "modified_at" timestamp(6) NULL,
    "project_id" int8 NOT NULL,
    "note_id" int8,
    "type" varchar(50) NOT NULL COLLATE "default",
    "is_public" bool NOT NULL DEFAULT false,
    "state" varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'ACTIVE'::character varying COLLATE "default",
    "mime_type" text COLLATE "default",
    "internal_type" text COLLATE "default",
    "is_template" bool NOT NULL,
    "has_filled_data" bool NOT NULL
)
WITH (OIDS=FALSE);
ALTER TABLE "intellinotedb"."external_resource" OWNER TO "intellinote";

-- ----------------------------
--  Primary key structure for table external_resource
-- ----------------------------
ALTER TABLE "intellinotedb"."external_resource" ADD PRIMARY KEY ("id") NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;

-- ----------------------------
--  Uniques structure for table external_resource
-- ----------------------------
ALTER TABLE "intellinotedb"."external_resource" ADD CONSTRAINT "external_resource_note_id_key" UNIQUE ("note_id") NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;

-- ----------------------------
--  Foreign keys structure for table external_resource
-- ----------------------------
ALTER TABLE "intellinotedb"."external_resource" ADD CONSTRAINT "external_resource_note_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("note_id") REFERENCES "intellinotedb"."note" ("id") ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;
ALTER TABLE "intellinotedb"."external_resource" ADD CONSTRAINT "external_resource_project_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY ("project_id") REFERENCES "intellinotedb"."project" ("id") ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION NOT DEFERRABLE INITIALLY IMMEDIATE;
```
````

And my model:

````
```
Waterline = require('waterline');

module.exports = Waterline.Collection.extend({
  tableName: 'external_resource',
  meta: {
    schemaName: process.env.WATERLINE_SCHEMA || 'intellinotedb'
  },
  connection: process.env.WATERLINE_DB || 'localhost',
  attributes: {
    id: {
      type: 'integer',
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
      unique: true,
      size: 8
    },
    external_id: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      size: 2000
    },
    version_id: {
      type: 'string',
      size: 2000
    },
    url: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      size: 5000
    },
    name: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      size: 4000
    },
    size: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 8
    },
    creator: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      size: 50
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: 'datetime',
      columnName: 'created_at'
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: 'datetime',
      columnName: 'modified_at'
    },
    project_id: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true
    },
    note_id: {
      type: 'integer',
      required: true,
      size: 8
    },
    type: {
      type: 'string',
      defaultsTo: 'FILE',
      required: true,
      size: 50
    },
    is_public: {
      type: 'boolean',
      defaultsTo: true,
      required: true
    },
    state: {
      type: 'string',
      enum: ['ACTIVE', 'DELETED'],
      defaultsTo: 'ACTIVE',
      required: true,
      size: 100
    },
    mime_type: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true
    },
    internal_type: {
      type: 'string',
      defaultsTo: 'REGULAR',
      required: true
    },
    is_template: {
      type: 'boolean',
      defaultsTo: false,
      required: false
    },
    has_filled_data: {
      type: 'boolean',
      defaultsTo: false,
      required: false
    }
  }
});

```
````

Answer (score 1):

The migrate function needs to be on each model and not on the connection. As per this thread: https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/1472